# How do I initialize the drive_service object from the Google Drive API with Python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

All the tutorials on the Google Drive API [website](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) have an object, `drive_service` that is initialized previously to the point where the provided code snippet picks up, but no explanation about what it is, does or how it should be built.  I am using Python.

[This is the example I am trying to do](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

I was able to get authenticated with quickstart.py with no issues.

Here is my code:

```
file_id = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M'
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

Here are some more examples:

[this one](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder)

[another one](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch)

[and another](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to know the difference between `service` of `service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)` and `drive_service` of those URLs.
- You want to create 2 scripts of `This is the example I am trying to do` and `Here is my code:`.
- You confirmed that the Quickstart for python worked.

For this, how about this answer?

### 1. About `service` and `drive_service`:

`service` of `service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)` of "Python Quickstart" is the same with `drive_service` of those URLs. So `service` includes the authorization for using the API (in this case, it's Drive API v3.). So the sample script of "Python Quickstart" can be modified can be also used as the script of authorization.

### 2. Script of `This is the example I am trying to do`:

This is a sample script for `This is the example I am trying to do`. This sample script uploads a local file to Google Drive. In this case, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` is used as the scope. Here, there is one important point. You can see the script of authorization copied and pasted from the Quickstart.

**When in your local folder, `token.pickle` has already been created with the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` when you run the Quickstart script, please delete it, and reauthorize the scope again. By this, new scope is reflected to the access token. Please be careful this.**

#### Sample script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    file_metadata = {'name': '###'}  # Please set filename.
    media = MediaFileUpload('###', mimetype='###', resumable=True)  # Please set filename and mimeType of the file you want to upload.
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- When `resumable=True` is used at `MediaFileUpload`, the large file can be uploaded by the resumable upload.

### 3. Script of `Here is my code:`:

This is a sample script for `Here is my code`. This sample script downloads a file from Google Drive to the local PC. In this case,`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and/or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` can be used as the scope. Here, as a test case, in order to use the `token.pickle` file created at above section 2, the scope is not changed from `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`. So you can use the script without reauthorizing the scopes.

#### Sample script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    file_id = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M'
    request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- In this script, Google Docs files (Spreadsheet, Document, Slides and so on) cannot be exported. The files except for Google Docs file can be downloaded. So please be careful this.
- In this case, the downloaded file is not created as a file. So please be careful this. If you want to download the file as a file, please modify `fh = io.BytesIO()` to `fh = io.FileIO("### filename ###", mode='wb')`.

### Note:

- In this case, as the important point, when the scopes are modified, it is required to delete `token.pickle` and reauthorize the scopes. Please be careful this.

### References:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

Comment: MediaIoBaseDownload is missing